# 'Postpone' or 'postphone'?

Tags: orthography

I was taught that the word **postpone** was spelled as I just spelled it, but recently I have seen a rise in the spelling **postphone** (or **post phone**). At first, I thought it was just a spelling error, but I have begun to see it more and more in official contexts.

Historically, the first spelling is definitely more accurate as you can see in the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=postpone) and in [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=postpone%2C+postphone%2C+post+phone&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). But also notice in the Google Ngram results that recently there has been a slight decline in the use of **postpone**. If you remove **postpone** from the Ngram query, you will see that the decline is accompanied by a rise in the use of **postphone** and **post phone**.

Are these new spellings becoming an acceptible alternative? Or is this simply a case of the rise in a misspelling accompanying more people having access to publication?

---

- [An example of 'postphone'](http://books.google.com/books?id=jzy2HqpCzFQC&pg=PA133&dq=%22postphone%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nKcwUu_hO6TYyQH7xoG4Dw&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22postphone%22&f=false)
- [An example of 'post phone'](https://sites.google.com/site/smcjcr/the-jcr/jcr-Polotic/jcr-meeting-minutes/jcrmeetingminutesfrom11112012)

---

**BONUS:** The best answer will explain *why* this variant spelling is so common, if possible.

Comment: I've never heard of "post phone".  Can you add a link to a source for this phrase to your answer?

Comment: Thanks for adding the links.  I'm calling those typos.  It is an interesting phenomena though!  I always learn something new from this site! :-)

Comment: If we type the word postphone , even auto spell checkers show red underline which clearly means this is just a misspelled word..

Comment: @Sweet72 Spell-check is by far not proof of anything.

Comment: I know it was just a funny comment..sorry I forgot to write lol...

Comment: I had a coworker that used "postphone" when she wanted to postpone something. What was particularly funny about it was that she initially wrote "postphone" and in subsequent emails changed to "post phone" and "post-phone". My guess is that she was trying to figure out why Outlook didn't like her spelling.

Comment: When I grew up it was postphone but always thought it should be spelled differently. I just came on to find out why we type phone instead of pone. Perhaps it is a regional English type of thing. I am from Wisconsin and frequently see postphone.

Comment: Spell "postpone" as "post pone" and likely many spell checkers will "correct" it to "post phone".  Then someone realizes it should be only one word and removes the blank, without noticing the added "h".

Comment: @HotLicks Excellent observation, worthy of another answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Oh, please, that *hurts*.  This is simply a case of the rise in a misspelling accompanying more people having access to publication, as you say.

"Postphone" is what happens after you drop your cellphone into the toilet, or if someone drives a car into the pole holding up your phone line.  Or you run out of money and your carrier truns off your service.

Of course, "postphone" might be a telephone attached to a post.  Hard to say for sure.

Except that whoever is spelling it "postphone" needs to be beaten with a wet noodle.

Horrifying.

Comment: That's how I felt about it too, but I wanted to check since I've seen it in a lot of official contexts lately. Sadly, in my personal experience, more than the correct spelling.

Comment: I guess I am not getting out enough, but I'd never seen this before.  Probably a good thing, since it would have driven up my blood pressure.  I guess I am humorless prig when it comes to egregious spelling mistakes.  Sad.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to check before I started correcting it in my superiors' writing, since they exclusively use the incorrect spelling.

Comment: And for clarification, yes, I am requested to edit my superiors' writing frequently, so it wouldn't be a case of me being a spelling Nazi.

Comment: INHO, that's the only good form of Nazi.  I have little or no patience for poor spelling.  I think it must be in my jeans.  Errr, genes.

Answer (score 2):

The original word "postpone" hasn't changed either its pronunciation, spelling or meaning. The links that you have provided seem to have misspelled the word.

However, the correct meaning of "postphone" as per Urban Dictionary is as follows :

**postphone**

A verb meaning "to put off a phone call until a later time."

E.g. : I know you want to talk, but the plane's about to take off. We'll have to **postphone**.

You can view this link : http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=postphone

Comment: I highly suspect that "postphone" as Urban Dictionary defines it has formed *since* the misspelling of "postpone" had already arisen.

Comment: Exactly right. The Urban dictionary was updated in 2010. It's easy to find postphone in 20 year old messages.

Answer (score 0):

"Postpone" comes from the Latin "post", meaning "after", plus "ponere", "to put" or "to place".

"Postphone" in the same sense is a horrific neologism.  In the "phone" sense, it seems to make sense, and is shorter than "I'll have to call you later".

Comment: You've added no new information here. The first sentence is already in my Online Etymology source, and the second is identical to Sweet72's inaccurate guess of the origin of "postphone" based on Urban Dictionary.

Answer (score -3):

I am sure it was originally spelled as postphone.  The reason I am so sure because I still vividly remember the scene when my teacher corrected the pronunciation of my classmate, who pronounced this word as what it spelled i.e. post phone”.  It was in 1979 when I was in Secondary 4.  The teacher said “in English, “ph” should always pronounce as if it is an “f”. However, postphone is an exception.  It should pronounce like a “b” i.e. “postbone”. “
I don’t know when it started to spell as postpone without the letter “h”.  I also try to prove it to my younger friends by surfing net but vain.  I suspect it has been changed long before we have the internet.

Comment: I have dictionaries older than 1979. It **never** was *postphone*. It was always *postpone*, all the time since the Roman Empire.

Comment: (1) Lots of teachers are wrong. Yours appears to have been grievously so. (2) I live in the US, and (many *many* years ago) I attended “Elementary School” (grades 1-6), “Junior High School”  (grades 7 and 8), and “High School”  (grades 9-12, but also called “freshman”, “sophomore”, “junior” and “senior”).  I’ve grown accustomed to hearing younger Americans refer to “Middle School” (although I still cringe a little every time I hear it), but I have no idea what “Secondary 4”  means.  You might want to refer to school years as grades (1-12) or by the age you were at the time (typical grade+5±1).

Comment: @Scott What makes you think that user320547 is American?  Secondary 4 almost makes sense in the UK context and, I suspect, might be perfectly standard in Australia or New Zealand. The grade system is not operated in the UK, pupils transfer to the next year by chronological age not by achievement which is what I understand happens in the US. Secondary 4 would then be the fourth year of secondary schooling, ie roughly 14 years of age regardless of achevement.

Comment: @BoldBen no one says "Secondary 4" in Australia. If it's referring to the 4th year-level in a secondary school (aka high school), it would be referred to as Year 10, depending on that particular State/Territory's system for year levels.

Comment: @BoldBen: (1) What makes you think I believe that user320547 is American?  I didn’t say anything like that.  (2) The U.S. system is almost 100% chronological.  Occasionally an advanced student will skip a grade, or a struggling student will repeat a grade, but these events are very rare.

Comment: @Scott I thought you believed they were American because you did not recognise Secondary 4 and said that they might want to refer to school years as "grades" which are probably as meaningless to them as Secondary 4 is to you.

Comment: @BoldBen: Yeah, that doesn’t make any sense. … … … … … … … … … … But, really, “1st grade” through “12th grade” aren’t universally understood?  Can you suggest what terminology would be most portable?  Chappo indicates that “Year 10” would be used in Australia, but I don’t know what it means.  Is it the same as “10th grade” in America?

Comment: @Scott I don't think there is a truly portable terminology, not all countries start and finsh school education at the same age and not every education authority in a given country (where education is publically funded) uses the same terminology and neither do privately funded schools in the same country. Just in the UK it's [this complicated](https://www.google.com/search?q=uk+scool+years&oq=uk+scool+years&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.17089j0j8&client=tablet-android-pega&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#imgrc=zs_vr5-ecErPtM:) so an internationally agreed terminology is probably impossible.

Comment: Wow, we really are divided by our common language.  But I’ll fall back on one thing I said in my original comment:  We agree on what a year is, and we agree on what “age” means (we do, right?), so we can use the person’s age at the time as a measure that we can all understand.  Sure, there may be differences between school systems, or even between schools in the same city — for example, I was 15 when I first started calculus, and 16 when I took thermodynamics — but it offers at least a rough comparison.  (P.S. Apparently “Year 10” is equivalent to American “9th grade”.)